# Javascript issue causing IE to fail

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting this error

```
Invalid character line 6254 character 9
```

the code there is

```
return eval("(" + string + ")")
```

I did a

```
console.log(string)
```

here is the json result

Every other browser it loads fine, just nothing any version of IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a valid JSON-String (check [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/))
There are unescaped newlines in "sqltotal"